# Nested materialized views find out actions on commit?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, materialized-views

I'd like to find out what actions (i.e. selects, inserts, updates) a database does in response to say:

insert into T (col_x, col_y, col_z) values (val_x, val_y, val_z);

T in this case is a table with a materialized view log but has a tree of nested materialized views which are based on it which refresh on commit. (e.g. T1 is based on T, T2 is based on T1 and U1 etc).

I want to see what the database does in response to the commit, so I can see if their are things I could do to speed up the process (i.e. add indexes or modify the materialized views).

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require database system user/direct machine access, but its ok if that is the only solution possible.

Comment: +1 for original problems posted, but if you know the materialized logs based on this table, you know even what happens when you insert in this table. However, it is important to know that in case on refresh on commit all the DML implied is done in the same transaction. It does not commit until all the MV are refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is start a database trace by

```
 exec dbms_monitor.database_trace_enable();
```

This will trace everything that's happening in the database to the udump dir.
then just

```
 grep "MV_NAME" *
```

This will output all trace files which had anything to do with your MVs.
After that you'll have to to summarize the traces so you could better understand them by using tkprof.

Don't forget to disable the database trace.

Daniel